# Why don't we have a on-hold or duplicates filter under the questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, filtering

I was wondering why don't we have on-hold, duplicate, low-quality, closed questions filter under the questions? I know that there are a lot of new users who do not bother to read any documentation on how to ask a good question.

If we have a filter for closed, low quality, on-hold questions, maybe new users may see them and try not to ask questions like that, then we will not have so many low quality questions. It's very hard finding a good question to answer these days. Most of the questions are poorly asked or are duplicates.

Comment: If you do not mind please share why the down vote?

Comment: I'm quite new on meta, but my guess is that if someone sees a feature-request they disagree with then downvoting is a way to show it.

Comment: All right... :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that there are a lot of new users who do not bother to read any
>   documentation on how to ask a good question and etc..

I think most people here share your view on this. However, I don't think your feature request will help any in this regard.

Consider a new user signing up on SO for the first time. Either this user has tried searching for his/hers question on google/SO *or* SO is the first place they try.

If asking a question on SO is the first attempt at solving the problem, "Hey, someone else can do this for me, so why bother searching for it myself.", then what are the odds this user will first go through **old, bad and unrelated questions** to see how **not to ask** a question?

If asking a question on SO is not the first attempt at solving the problem, the user has most likely already visited a few related questions on SO. The user will immediately (from the +/- score) tell if these questions are considered good or bad questions by the community.

The problem is: **New users don't necessarily care**, as long as they might get an answer.

Side note, the criterion would have to be "bad **and unanswered** questions", as showing "bad and answered questions" would serve the opposite purpose.

Comment: Yes you are right. But a new user asks a questions.. Its bad and people will post a link of how to ask a good question(I do this) the user may read it and then want to explore the site then he may find the filtered questions useful for him to avoid asking bad questions.

Comment: I think Stack overflow needs a feature that stops new users from asking bad quality questions because the number of bad questions are increasing day by day and if this keeps going on site will have more bad questions than good questions also it will be hard for people to search on Stack overflow for their problems because of so many bad questions...

Comment: And everyone agrees with you (as you will see if you browse through high score questions and answers on meta). Personally, I just don't think your proposed solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I think the filter should work the other way, and filter out certain types of questions.  Also it should be by category of closing:

- on-hold, duplicates.
- unclear
- too broad
- off-topic
- primarily opinion-based